# Join 2 or 3 MySQL tables with conditional request

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables :

track:

```
id, title, artist_id, album_id, description, cover
```

artist:

```
id, name, bio
```

album:

```
id, title, description, artist_id, cover
```

I have actually this request:

```
SELECT * FROM `track`
LEFT JOIN album ON track.album_id=album.id
LEFT JOIN artist ON album.artist_id=artist.id
```

But how can I, if `track.album_id = 0`, make that conditionnale join `LEFT JOIN artist ON track.artist_id=artist.id`, to have artist information if track have no album ?

Comment: Have you tried running this query? If I understand your question correctly, using `LEFT JOIN like you say you are doing, does exactly what you are asking for, so your query should just work.

Comment: no, what's I want is :

    SELECT * FROM `track`
    if(track.album_id >0)
    {
    LEFT JOIN album ON track.album_id=album.id
    LEFT JOIN artist ON album.artist_id=artist.id
    }
    else
    {
    LEFT JOIN artist ON track.artist_id=artist.id
    }

Answer (score 1):

If I'm understanding correctly, you want to have artist information displayed if the track has no album. You can use a `CASE` in your `SELECT` statement to fill in information or `SELECT` some other information.

```
SELECT col1, col2, ..., CASE
    WHEN track.album_id IS NULL # or = 0
        THEN 'Artist Info'
    ELSE track.album_id
    AS coln
FROM track
...
```

Also, always use a column list

Comment: maybe I haven't understand but impossible to get a valid request

Answer (score -1):

I might try

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT * FROM `track`
LEFT JOIN album ON track.album_id=album.id
LEFT JOIN artist ON album.artist_id=artist.id) WHERE album.id IS NULL
```

However, I don't understand why you're using 0 in `track.album_id` to mean no album. This tells me you're not using a foreign key constraint, since if you were, the constraint would fail where `track.album_id` = 0. I recommend running this:

```
UPDATE track SET album_id = NULL where album_id = 0;
ALTER TABLE track ADD FOREIGN KEY album_id REFERENCES album (id);
```

Comment: I'm a mysql noob and I have maybe make my database with my feet, but it's for a personal test. I have a sql error with you request